# write.csv writes an empty file

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I created a data.frame cust_data_360 from 2 data sets cust_data and cust_demo using following sql query : Used SQLDF package

```
cust_data_360 <- sqldf('select * from cust_data where ID not in(select ID from cust_demo)')
```

When I try to write the output using write.csv like :

```
write.csv('cust_data_360', file = 'cust_data_360.csv')
```

The file is written at the working directory but its blank. Am not sure what is the problem? The cust_data_360 has 44 observations with 10 variables.

Comment: You don't need quote for `cust_data_360`

Comment: @akrun : Thanks!! That's so stupid of me and yeah I did get those 2 lines in the CSV file as well.

Comment: @akrun : I have one more question related to within() function, if you can help. Also, do I need to post it separately?

Comment: Thanks I marked the answer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify @akrun - you don't quote the name of the object you are writing. Use `write.csv(cust_data_360, file="cust_data_360.csv")`

The CSV you created shouldn't actually be empty:

```
> write.csv('cust_data_360', file = 'cust_data_360.csv')
>
```

Now view it (Linux command line, in Windows, open in Notepad)

```
$ cat cust_data_360.csv 
"","x"
"1","cust_data_360"
```

It contains those two lines for me.